# Different behavior of character and integer array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is a small code in c++ where I am creating two arrays of char and int data types respectively.However the same print operation is behaving differently for both the arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[5]={'h','e','l','l','o'};
    int b[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

    cout<<a;                       //displays the string "hello"
    cout<<"\n"<<b;                 //displays the address of b[0]
    return(0);
}
```

I expected the output to be the address of the first element of both the arrays i.e. address of a[0] and b[0] respectively however char type array is behaving differently in this case.

Comment: This is absolutely common behaviour in C and C++: a pointer to `char` is treated as a type of string but pretty much every Standard Library function - the string must be terminated with a `NUL` character, or `'\0'`, so in fact your program is [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because it doesn't meet that criterion. Your program could break in all kinds of strange ways (including **appearing** to work normally) because the library function reading the string doesn't know when to stop.

Comment: Actually you're very lucky that `cout << a` seemingly works. Because in reality what you have is *undefined behavior* as `cout` tries to use `a` as a null-terminated byte string. Which `a` isn't.

Comment: I'd say very *unlucky*! The best you can hope for with Undefined Behaviour is a really obvious crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a special overload of operator << for `cout` that treats `char *` arguments as null terminated strings and prints the entire string.

If you want to print the address cast it to `void *`.

```
cout << (void *) a;
```